# I got System.NullReferenceException when using Runspace for calling a powershell script in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, powershell

I'm using visual basic in visual studio to call a PS script after clicking a button but it stops and reporting an error System.NullReferenceException with Runspace because MyRunSpace results to be "Nothing".

```
Private Sub Skans_Button(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RunScript(LoadScript("C:\Users\RosarioPugliese\source\repos\VBPowerScript - WIP\PowerScript.ps1"))
End Sub

Private Function LoadScript(FileName As String) As String
    Try
        Dim Stream As New StreamReader(FileName)
        Dim FileContents As New StringBuilder()
        Dim CurLine As String = ""
        Do
            CurLine = Stream.ReadLine()
            FileContents.Append(CurLine + vbCrLf)
        Loop Until CurLine Is Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim errorText As String = "The file could not be read:"
        errorText += Err.Description + "\n"
        Return errorText
    End Try

End Function
Private Function RunScript(ScriptText As String) As String
    Try

        Dim MyRunSpace As Runspace
        MyRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()
        MyRunSpace.Open()
        Dim MyPipeline As Pipeline = MyRunSpace.CreatePipeline()
        MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript(ScriptText)
        'MyPipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String")
        Dim Results As Collection(Of PSObject) = MyPipeline.Invoke()
        MyRunSpace.Close()
        Dim MyStringBuilder As New StringBuilder()
        For Each obj As PSObject In Results
            MyStringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString())
        Next
        Return MyStringBuilder.ToString()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim errorText As String = "The file could not be read:"
        errorText += Err.Description + "\n"
        Return errorText
    End Try

End Function
```

Any advice?

Comment: Your function `LoadScript` doesn't return the value of `FileContents.ToString()`. It only outputs something if there is an error.

Comment: BTW, why not simply have only this `return File.ReadAllText(FileName)` in the Try block?

Comment: @Theo I'll try your suggestions. Anyway there's an easier way, or perhaps one without this kind of issues, for calling a PowerShell script?